# Etimología y origen de "parranda"

Tags: etimología

En el diccionario de la lengua, aparece parranda con 'Etimología discutida', sin dar otras pistas de su discución. Una rápida consulta en internet sugiere un posible [origen vasco](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/parranda), otro desde *[farra](https://definiciona.com/parranda/)* (árabe, luego portugués y de ahí al español) y según su significado, podría venir de jarana (especulando, con 2 o 3 sonidos modificados...), que nos deja de nuevo con un origen incierto. Ahora, la palabra no tiene más de siglo y medio en escrito (eso muestra el CORDE) y se escribe a ambos lados del Atlántico (en buena parte de Hispanoamérica y de España se parrandeaba en el siglo XIX) así que por su amplia difusión, da a entender que viene la palabra es cercana a 1800.

En particular, ¿cuál es la teoría más aceptada y el origen de esta palabra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definición de Parranda**

**Parranda** n. fem,

1. COLOQUIAL Diversión animada, en especial la que consiste en recorrer distintos lugares donde se bebe o se baila.

*"estuvo toda la noche de parranda por el centro de la ciudad"*

2. Grupo de personas que salen de noche tocando o cantando para divertirse.

*Otras acepciones habituales*;

- Fiesta.
- Rumba.
- Cantos.
- Baile regional del Sureste de España.
- Distintos tipos de cantes que se hacen en cuadrillas y agrupaciones.
- Grupo de músicos itinerantes que tocan en distintos lugares durante la noche.
- Cualquier diversión.
- En el ámbito del Salvador golpes que dan varias personas con la mano, sobre la cabeza de otro.
- Nombre de una Zarzuela en tres actos con música de Francisco Alonso y libreto de Luis Fernández Ardavín, 1928.

---

**INTRODUCCION AL ESTUDIO**

Por los datos leídos y recopilados antes de realizar este mini-estudio, la voz "**parranda**" no se había documentado hasta el año 1815 en Tomás Aguiló.

Por otro lado Corominas creía que el "parranda" utilizado en la lengua catalana procedía del vasco o el español y hoy en día el origen vasco por ende es el criterio más consolidado, *donde **parre**  en vasco significa risa y **andana** montón, así "Parranda" significaría un "montón de risas"* .([https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/parranda#:~:text=Etimolog%C3%ADa,significar%C3%ADa%20un%20mont%C3%B3n%20de%20risas.](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/parranda#:%7E:text=Etimolog%C3%ADa,significar%C3%ADa%20un%20mont%C3%B3n%20de%20risas.)).

Corominas a este respecto opinaba que la voz "parranda" era poco castiza para ser verdadera del castellano e igualmente, poco arraigada tanto en el Principado como en Mallorca o en el País Valenciano, (*Miscell̃ània Giuseppe Tavani, Volumen 2, pag. 105*). Por otro lado, las procedencias portuguesa y árabe, se encuentran hoy en día descartadas.

---

Gracias a las nuevas tecnologías y al avance de relacionar y cruzar datos, mucha de la "antigua etimología" esta en aras de ser revisada para ser puestas al día, así, tanto las muestras del CORDE como las inclinaciones e ideas de otros autores, son solo una referencia que sirven de ayuda al estudioso que sigue profundizando en estos temas y que entiende que pueden existir otras perspectivas.

La entrada más antigua encontrada en el CORDE es de 1877:

*Diablos, hombre! Vengo por ti para llevarte a una **parranda**, donde hay muchachas de arroz con leche y ca **  1877. Palma, Ricardo. Tradiciones peruanas, cuarta serie PERÚ*.

http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html

*En el enlace de más arriba no aparece directamente la palabra, hay que buscarla escribiendo dentro del primer cuadro y posteriormente en otra pantalla buscar el botón de recuperar obtención de ejemplos.*

---

**RESUMEN DEL ESTUDIO**

El término "**parranda**", tal como lo conocemos en la actualidad es la deformación de algunas formas verbales del antiguo verbo, "**pando**", que nos dará entre otras muchas formaciones, la palabra "**panda (dim. pandilla)**" y que nos ayuda a comprender, reflejando su significado más próximo con la "parranda" tradicional, como panda, agrupación de amigos, "irse de parranda", irse con la panda (de amigos), irse con la "pandilla". Este "pando", recogerá a su vez acepciones de otras voces cercanas que han ido añadiéndose con el tiempo al término "**parranda**" ya que es una palabra con distintos homógrafos y esto permite ampliar los contextos.

En el primer diccionario General Etimológico de la Lengua Española de 1894 al hablar de "**pandilla**" se dice;

"...*Pandilla, cualquier reunión de gente, y en especial la que se forma con objeto de divertirse en el campo*."

Los conceptos clásicos de "pando" como abrir, curvo, curvar, doblar, redondeado, encorvado... dejarán paso al "**pando Hispánico**" de la Edad Media, que junto a otras palabras como "pandochaus" procedentes también del latín hispánico son las responsables de que "**parranda**" tome el sentido de cuadrilla, agrupación y se le relacione con la música, la bebida, el cante, el baile y acabe como fiesta o divertimento junto a un grupo de personas. A esto añadir otras acepciones como lento o tardío...

---

**PROCEDENCIA Y EVOLUCION DE PARRANDA**

En última instancia "**parranda**" procedería del verbo latino "***pando - is - pandi - passum/pansum - pandere***", que junto con el  adjetivo ***pandus - a - um*** y otras palabras del latín hispánico, han dado lugar a términos, algunos ya en desuso, como "pandorga (junta de muchos instrumentos)", "pandurría (hoy bandurria)", "pandero (en sentido de tonto)"...la voz "banda (panda)", como agrupación, también procede de panda, aunque actualmente se le atribuyan otros orígenes inciertos.

La evolución de las distintas formas verbales de "pando" en  tiempos de perfecto, participio, supino... como "pandisse","passurum esse (passus sum)", "passŭm/pansum", permitió en algunos casos la deformación del fonema "s" que por **rotacismo** se convertiría en "r", como en el caso de la palabra latina "flos", que en español daría la voz "flor".  Posteriormente habría una transformación por "**metátesis**", es decir, el cambio de lugar de los sonidos dentro de la misma palabra, como "vidua en viuda" o "animalia en alimaña". Así, se pasaría por rotacismo de "pandisse" a "pandirre" y por "metátesis de "pandirre a parrendi", de aquí al "parronda" del actual asturiano y al "**parranda**" español.

---

La voz "parranda", tanto como nombre propio como acompañada del verbo ir, "ir de parranda" es bastante anterior a 1800, aunque su documentación haya sido más tardía.

---

[image]

---

Dentro del teatro breve valenciano, aparece el titulo de una obra atribuida a Carlos León, "***Parranda** y Bufalampolla venen del Norte, cridats de Cènto y Tito. Els quatre formen un platicó ensomiat, ó tal vòlta lo que pinta, pinta. Cènto y Tito*...", de 1811, en plena Guerra de la Independencia Española antinapoleónica y donde "**Parranda**" es utilizado como nombre propio de uno de los personajes de la pequeña obra escrita en valenciano, la cual servirá de propaganda para la lucha contra el ejercito francés. Esta pieza teatral se encuentra también hermanada tanto por algunos de los personajes como por alguno de los temas y el ambiente con otra titulada, *Junta  secreta* de  1787/1788, donde también aparece el mismo personaje llamado "**Parranda**".

[image]

En esta última obra "**Junta secreta**", el término "parranda", fue utilizado por Carlos León, tanto como nombre propio o apodo del personaje, "**Parranda**" y en el sentido habitual que conocemos de "**parranda**", cuando dice;

> Chirabolics. Eixe es el pleyt ; sempre vas de **parranda** , y no treballes: ergo.
>
> **Parranda**. Aixd, Chirabolics, en otros tiempos. Ara tot está perdtát.
> La fantasia y les mòdes ho tenen tot talát.

[image]

Otra alusión graciosa a "**parranda**" ya más tardía, de Arnal 1877, «*cuant te l'endús de **parranda**, / tots els caragols que apanda/ se'ls gasta en tu de rondó*»

---

Así, con esta "breve" puesta en escena de la palabra "**parranda**", concluimos para referirnos a ella de la manera tradicional, como "panda", "pandilla" o grupo de amigos que salen y se reúnen a escuchar música, a cantar, a bailar, a comer y a beber, descubriendo que la voz "**parranda**" ya se encontraba en uso e **impresa** en el S.XVIII y que de manera probable su existencia fuese anterior, estimando la fecha de su evolución entre la última parte del S. XVI y primeros del S. XVII, para ser tomada de forma habitual a partir de finales del S. XVII o principios del S. XVIII.